# React API calls giving "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app." error after deploying ReactJs app in Firebase server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am building a react js app where I am calling some API's.
My Backend is a NodeJs server deployed in GCloud.

When i'm running my React app on my local, its working fine. I'm able to get the response from the API . But when I have deployed the react app on firebase server I am getting an error "**You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.**" in the preview section of Network tab . And i've checked the Backend server logs, there is no request received. So the request is not even reaching my backend.

When i try calling the backend API in postman , it works fine and able to see the response and logs.

If anyone knows the solution, Please help!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The preview pane of the network tab does not execute JavaScript, so there you can see the "noscript" version of a website.